# Wix in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, wix

It seems that to create Windows installers with Wix and Visual Studio, the C# langage is required. What about projects written in c++?

Comment: What leads you do that conclusion? My WIX projects so far have been for C# deployments, but I don't see anything about WIX or its integration with Visual Studio that makes it specific only to C#.

Comment: When I was reading about the Wix toolset, I found the first sentence to deal with C#. Thanks all for the votes down, so supportive!

Comment: The hover text for the vote down button begins with "This question does not show any research effort..." Your comment says "I found the first sentence to deal with C#..." I think the vote down button has been used precisely for its intended purpose. Be considerate of the time people take to answer your questions by spending a little time of your own before you ask.

Comment: "Windows Installer" isn't a generic term for installers on Windows.  It's a very specific technology that came out in the summer of 1999.  Years before C# and the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WiX for any language and any project. Even for files without any projects.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require c# - please say what parts you need c# for.

Wix is nearly all written using xml-based scripts.

Comment: -1 for thinking that WiX XML is "script".  WiX is a declarative not imperative programming language that transforms into Windows Installer table data which is also declarative.  There is no scripting.

Comment: no, the inference in entirely yours. XML 'script' doesn't imply programming at all. (though 'programming' via configuration is a well known term)